# Random images are coming in carousel

Tags: javascript, html, slider, carousel

I have created a slider, it works fine but when I slide to next contents it shows the random images in the slider. I want to show these images as I have added them into the code. I don't want randomly sliding images.

Javascript

```
$('#myCarousel').carousel({
    interval: 000,
})

$('.carousel .item').each(function(){
    var next = $(this).next();
    if (!next.length) {
        next = $(this).siblings(':first');
    }
    next.children(':first-child').clone().appendTo($(this));

    for (var i=0;i<2;i++) {
        next=next.next();
        if (!next.length) {
            next = $(this).siblings(':first');
        }

        next.children(':first-child').clone().appendTo($(this));
    }
});
```

HTML

```
 <div class="carousel slide" id="myCarousel3" data-ride="carousel" data-interval="000" data-pause="hover">
            <div class="carousel-inner">

                <div class="item active">
                    <div class="col-xs-3"><img src="computers/img/dell.jpeg" alt=" " class="img-responsive thumb" />
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="item">
                    <div class="col-xs-3"><img src="computers/img/acer.jpg" alt=" " class="img-responsive thumb" />
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="item">
                    <div class="col-xs-3"><img src="computers/img/asus.jpg" alt=" " class="img-responsive thumb" />
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <a class="left carousel-control" href="#myCarousel3" data-slide="prev"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"></i></a>
            <a class="right carousel-control" href="#myCarousel3" data-slide="next"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></i></a>   
        </div>
```

Comment: Where are you going to specify the images

Comment: What comes to my mind is: Load all URL Pictures in an array and pick with `math.random()` a random number and display it.

Comment: Sir, I have edited the question. and I don't want to show random images. i want to show them in sequence @Doggo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in your for loop just change

```
    for (var i=0;i<1;i++) {
```

i < 2  to i < 1; I hope this is what you want, As i tried this and get the result are in sequence. 
please check
https://codepen.io/atulraj89/pen/zjRwxR
And if you want result to be something else,
pls explain.

Comment: I have run your code but it is giving the same result as random images in infinite loop.

Comment: okay now I am getting the images in sequence but I'm getting only 3 images at a time and the space for the fourth one is showing empty in that slider. So how can I remove that blank space for the fourth image?

Comment: Hi Harsh,

Use col-xs-4 instead of col-xs-3 for this in your code.
and if helpful pls upvote.
and if want four images then just add one more div with item class having image src url in it with col-xs-3, otherwise make it col-xs-4 in your html code.

Answer (score 0):

So I found an example on Bootstrap with Jquery and bootstrap.

HTML:

```
<div id="carouselExampleIndicators" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
    <ol class="carousel-indicators">
      <li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
      <li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="1"></li>
      <li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="2"></li>
    </ol>
    <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
      <!-- Slide One - Set the background image for this slide in the line below -->
      <div class="carousel-item active" style="background-image: url('computers/img/dell.jpeg')">
        <div class="carousel-caption d-none d-md-block">
          <h3>First Slide</h3>
          <p>This is a computer from Dell</p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <!-- Slide Two - Set the background image for this slide in the line below -->
      <div class="carousel-item" style="background-image: url('computers/img/acer.jpg')">
        <div class="carousel-caption d-none d-md-block">
          <h3>Second Slide</h3>
          <p>This is a computer from Acer</p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <!-- Slide Three - Set the background image for this slide in the line below -->
      <div class="carousel-item" style="background-image: url('computers/img/asus.jpg')">
        <div class="carousel-caption d-none d-md-block">
          <h3>Third Slide</h3>
          <p>This is a computer from Asus</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#carouselExampleIndicators" role="button" data-slide="prev">
      <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
      <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
    </a>
    <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#carouselExampleIndicators" role="button" data-slide="next">
      <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
      <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
    </a>
  </div>
```

CSS:

```
.carousel-item {
  height: 65vh;
  min-height: 300px;
  background: no-repeat center center scroll;
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
}
```

In your HTML you need to add the CSS, Jquery and bootstrap js.

```
<link href="vendor/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="vendor/jquery/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="css/your_css.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

Source: https://startbootstrap.com/template-overviews/half-slider/

Comment: thanks for the reply but I want to create a multi-item slider.